# Como transformar Array em variáveis distintas?

Tags: php, array

Eu tenho o seguinte `array` que me retorna os seguintes valores:

```
(
    [cliente] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => 1
                    [Name] => a
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [Code] => 2
                    [Name] => b
                )  
        )  
)
```

Tem algum jeito de eu pegar para cada *Code* transformar para uma variável `$stnCode` e para cada *Name* transformar para `$stnName`?

Porque depois quero inserir em banco de dados, onde a tabela `Cliente` recebe *Code* e *Name*.

Comment: Como assim? você quer uma variável que vai receber vários valores diferentes?

Comment: @JuniorNunes7 mais ou menos é que preciso inserir no banco de dados aquele array em uma tabela, que tem Code e Name também, então para cada array será inserido em um row da tabela.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode percorrer `$dados` indicando o sub-array `cliente`:

```
$dados = array('cliente' => array('0' => array('Code' => 1, 'Name' => 'a'),
                                  '1' => array('Code' => 2, 'Name' => 'b')));

foreach ($dados['cliente'] as $cliente) {
    $stnCode = $cliente['Code'];
    $stnName = $cliente['Name'];

    // Use $stnCode e $stnName aqui...

    echo $stnCode . ":" . $stnName . "\n";
}
```

<kbd>[Ver **DEMO**](http://ideone.com/rAM5J4)</kbd>